Form not passing values to query
me again, thanks for all the previous assistance. I am still working on the form from my previous question, almost to the end lol. Just need to get past this last hump of passing the values to the command to query AD. I am not using RSAT because I don't want it installed on random machines, so I found a way to query AD without installing RSAT, thanks to this module in this link AD module
Here is my code. The idea is for the get-ADUser to accept the input from the textbox.
Function Query_PUID{
 Import-Module $scriptPath\AD_Module.psm1
 $PUID=$TxtBoxInput.Text
 $PUID=Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$PUID'" | Select-Object -Property "Name"| ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name 
}
$TxtBoxOutput.Text = "$PUID" -join "`r`n"  # Join the lines with carriage return and newline

 }


Firts of all, the module you refer to does not have a Get-ADUser function, instead there is Get-NetUserPrincipal. Then it would be a lot better is you do not use the same variable name for different purposes in your function. Furthermore, in your previous question, there seems to be no $TxtBoxInput, but there is a control in your form called $PUIDTextbox. Did you change that in the meantime?

Thank you, not sure what you mean, "not using the same variable for different purposes in the same function", please elaborate. Are you saying I should not use the PUID variable the way I am currently using it? You are correct, in my previous question, I had not created the function for querying the PUID from AD yet, that was added later on as a way to make the form more restrictive to prevent typing in arbitrary information to pass as a PUID.

Ok, I made the change as suggested and used the Get-NetUserPrincipal as per the module. Only issue is, and not sure why, but for some reason once it returns the value for first query query, it won't pull for another. But if I run the same query from another script it works for any consecutive queries. I will post a different question for that if I can't figure why.
